# How to make method public for my project but not for public API?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I write SDK and I have header `MyClass.h` with public API.

Some methods are not written in header like `- (void)foo;` so users cannot use them.

However my other class use method `foo` but since its not registered in `MyClass.h` - I cannot use it also.

So in each class that want to call method `foo` I wrote:

```
@interface MyClass ()
- (void) foo;
@end
```

Is it legal? I need to write the same in 3 other classes and it looks bizarre.

So what is the best practice to *publish* method for internal usage but not for public API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new file. Use the “Objective-C File” template:

[image: choosing a file template]
For “File”, enter “Project”. For “File Type”, choose “Extension”. For “Class”, enter “MyClass” (or whatever your real class name is):

[image: setting the file options]

Xcode creates a new file named `MyClass_Project.h`. In this file, declare your project-only methods:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyClass ()

- (void)foo;

@end
```

Then, in every `.m` file that needs to use one of these methods, and in `MyClass.m`, import `MyClass_Project.h`. Any file that imports `MyClass_Project.h` does not need to also import `MyClass.h`.

Comment: why do I need to import `MyClass_Project.h` in `MyClass.m`?

Comment: So that the compiler will verify that your method signatures match, and that your class defines all of the methods declared in `MyClass_Project.h`.